# Old search results are showing in addeventlistener JavaScript. Inner.HTML = `` not working properly

Tags: javascript, search

I am working on an image search project. My problem is that if I type a keyword, the results are showing. If I again type another keyword, new results are showing. But the problem starts here once I click on load more button. It's showing the previous search results beneath to the new search results. If I continue to click load more button, after a few click, previous results are showing in the top and the new results are below to that. Please help me.

Here is my code

For JavaScript
search.js

```
let imgsearch = document.querySelector('.imgsearch')
let bsub =  document.querySelector('.bsub')
// let editorChoice = document.querySelector('.editorchoice')
let searchRes = document.querySelector('.searchresult')
// let searchUrlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
// let searchDetail =  searchUrlParam.get('tags')
let form = document.querySelector('form')
let discoverSearch = document.querySelector('.discoversearch')
let page = 1

function mySearch(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let query = document.querySelector('input').value
  searchResult(query)
  // bsub.removeEventListener('click', mySearch)
  // form.removeEventListener('submit', mySearch)
if(page === 1){
  searchRes.innerHTML = ``
  discoverMore.style.display = 'none'
  discoverSearch.style.display = 'block'
  
}
if(page === 1){
  discoverSearch.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    page++
    searchResult(query)
    searchRes.innerHTML = ``
  })
}
else {
    // searchRes.innerHTML = ``
    page++
    searchResult(query)
}
}




form.addEventListener('submit', mySearch)

bsub.addEventListener('click', mySearch)





async function searchResult(query){
    let searhUrl =  await fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=12345&q=${query}&page=${page}&per_page=24`) 
    let rawSearch = await searhUrl.json()
    let resultSearch =  rawSearch.hits
    console.log(rawSearch)
    for(let i = 0; i < resultSearch.length; i++){
      let itemSearch = resultSearch[i]
      let searchImg = itemSearch.previewURL
      let searchType = itemSearch.type
      let searchTag = itemSearch.tags 
      let itemId = itemSearch.id
      

      if(i % 3 === 0) {
          searchRes.innerHTML += `<div class="row">`
        }
       editorChoice.innerHTML = ``
       searchRes.innerHTML += `<a href="photos.html?id=${itemId}"><img src="${searchImg}" alt="${searchTag}"/></a>
       <p><a href="photos.html?id=${itemId}">${searchTag}</a></p>`
       
    }
    
}
```

For HTML

```
<div class="searchresult"></div>
```

Comment: `searchResult()` is an asynchronous function, but you're not calling it with `await`.

Comment: I found the solution. In mySearch(), I need to add   page = 1. It should be like this
```
function mySearch(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  query = document.querySelector('input').value;
  page = 1;
  searchResult();
if(page === 1){
  searchRes.innerHTML = ``;
  discoverMore.style.display = 'none';
  discoverSearch.style.display = 'block';
}
} ```